# getMenuInflater( ) method undefined issue in Android Context Menu creation

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-menu, android-contextmenu

I am trying to create a context menu item inside a fragment. But I am facing issue with the getMenuInflater() method. It is undefined. I have imported all the necessary packages. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class FeaturedFragment extends Fragment {
    public FeaturedFragment() {
    }
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_fragment,container,false);
        registerForContextMenu(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toggleview_menu, menu);
    }
}
```

here is my menu.xml

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
      <item android:id="@+id/toggle_view"
         android:title="Change to ListView"
         android:icon="@drawable/collections_view_as_grid"
         android:showAsAction="always" />
      <item android:id="@+id/grid_view"
         android:title="Grid View"
         android:orderInCategory="99"
         android:showAsAction="never" />
      <item android:id="@+id/list_view"
         android:title="List View"
         android:orderInCategory="99"
         android:showAsAction="never" />
  </menu>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Change:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
```

To this:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But my menu item is not shown in the view. I have edited my post with the menu xml file.

Comment: aren't you supposed to use `getMenuInflator()` within `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside an `Activity`?

Comment: Developer Guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu) says we can have it inside either an activity or fragment.

Comment: Inside a fragment, onCreateOptionMenu passes in a MenuInflater as the second parameter.  Answer given is fine.  But, if the inflater is provided in the parameters, I would opt for that, personal preference.

Comment: @Les - But this is about inside `onCreateContextMenu`, not `onCreateOptionsMenu`. No `MenuInflater` argument.